# how to get numbers from an array (array.length = 5) and transform each number (n) into a stack of n boxes in 5 separate DIVs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I've tried to code a simple 5 inputs(numbers) page to put the values into an array.
Then, I want to extract each number value to "convert" them into 5 different stacks of boxes.
I want to materialize these numbers into a more visual display.
I have to use ONLY Vanilla JS.
I'd like to create 5 different compartments to put these boxes.

here is my HTML, CSS and JS code.
For the moment, I've found how to distinguish the different numbers using some conditional color styling.

```js
let boxes = []
let length = boxes.length
const boxContainer = document.querySelector('#resultContainer')
const results = document.querySelector('.stack')
const button = document.querySelector('#qtyButton')
let getTas1
let getTas2
let getTas3
let getTas4
let getTas5

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fillArray()

  function fillArray() {
    getTas1 = document.querySelector('.Qty1').value
    getTas2 = document.querySelector('.Qty2').value
    getTas3 = document.querySelector('.Qty3').value
    getTas4 = document.querySelector('.Qty4').value
    getTas5 = document.querySelector('.Qty5').value
    boxes.push(getTas1, getTas2, getTas3, getTas4, getTas5)
  }

  boxes.forEach((res) => displayBoxes(res))

  
})

function displayBoxes(res) {
  for (b = 0; b < res; b++) {
    let box = document.createElement('div')
    box.classList.add('compart')
    switch (res) {
      case getTas1:
        box.classList.add('red')
        break
      case getTas2:
        box.classList.add('blue')
        break
      case getTas3:
        box.classList.add('green')
        break
      case getTas4:
        box.classList.add('yellow')
        break
      case getTas5:
        box.classList.add('pink')
        break
    }

    box.innerHTML = `<div></div>`
    results.appendChild(box)
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 1050px;
  margin: auto;
}

.formContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.buttonZone {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.formTitle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inputZone {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#resultContainer {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
}

.stack {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.compart {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 3px;
}

.case {
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="formContainer">
    <div class="formTitle">How many boxes ?</div>
    <div class="inputZone">
      <input type="number" class="Qty1">
      <input type="number" class="Qty2">
      <input type="number" class="Qty3">
      <input type="number" class="Qty4">
      <input type="number" class="Qty5">
    </div>
    <div class="buttonZone">
      <button id="qtyButton">Go</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="resultContainer">
    <div class="stack"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: so for each group of boxes you want in a div (div 1 has group 1 boxes, div 2...etc)?

Comment: yes, in fact, I know I'll have 5 different numbers and I'd like to materialize 5 different stacks of n boxes into 5 "rooms" which could represent a width of 20% of the blue zone space, am I clear ? a sort of |____|____|____|____|____| , you know ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming sequential btn clicks should reset each container so clear out result (`document.querySelector('.stack').innerHTML=''`). Next I pass the index with `res` so that I can reference it in `color` list for css to shorten code, though as I mention using pure css would be cleaner probably. To create `div` dynamically create a new div with class group before the list, add the color divs, and add that group to result after the loop.

```js
let boxes = []
let length = boxes.length
const button = document.querySelector('#qtyButton')
const color = ['red','blue','green','yellow','pink'] // could be css, as each group has diff color
// change .red to #group1 div
const results = document.querySelector('.stack')
let getTas1
let getTas2
let getTas3
let getTas4
let getTas5

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fillArray()

  function fillArray() {
    getTas1 = document.querySelector('.Qty1').value
    getTas2 = document.querySelector('.Qty2').value
    getTas3 = document.querySelector('.Qty3').value
    getTas4 = document.querySelector('.Qty4').value
    getTas5 = document.querySelector('.Qty5').value
    document.querySelector('.stack').innerHTML=''
    boxes.push(getTas1, getTas2, getTas3, getTas4, getTas5)
  }

  boxes.forEach((res,i) => displayBoxes(res,i))

  console.log('résultat :', boxes)
})

function displayBoxes(res,idx) {
  let group=document.createElement('div')
  group.classList.add('group')
  for (b = 0; b < res; b++) {
    let box = document.createElement('div')
    box.classList.add('compart')
    box.classList.add(color[idx])

    box.innerHTML = `<div></div>`
    group.appendChild(box)
  }
  results.append(group)
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 1050px;
  margin: auto;
}

.formContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.buttonZone {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.formTitle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inputZone {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#resultContainer {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
}

.stack {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width:100%;
}
.group {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.compart {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 3px;
}

.case {
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="formContainer">
    <div class="formTitle">How many boxes ?</div>
    <div class="inputZone">
      <input type="number" class="Qty1">
      <input type="number" class="Qty2">
      <input type="number" class="Qty3">
      <input type="number" class="Qty4">
      <input type="number" class="Qty5">
    </div>
    <div class="buttonZone">
      <button id="qtyButton">Go</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="resultContainer">
    <div class="stack">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you ! I think I can use flexbox and flex direction : row to put them in the right way.  In fact, I was wondering if It's possible to make these 5 div dynamically ? Do I absolutely have to force it in my HTML code before starting ? I thought it was possible using JS, am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Removed unwanted function calling on event listener.

I have just modified you code

```js
let boxes = []
let length = boxes.length
const boxContainer = document.querySelector('#resultContainer')
const results = document.querySelector('.stack')
const button = document.querySelector('#qtyButton')
let getTas1
let getTas2
let getTas3
let getTas4
let getTas5

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  results.innerHTML = ``
  boxes = []
  getTas1 = document.querySelector('.Qty1').value
  getTas2 = document.querySelector('.Qty2').value
  getTas3 = document.querySelector('.Qty3').value
  getTas4 = document.querySelector('.Qty4').value
  getTas5 = document.querySelector('.Qty5').value
  boxes.push(getTas1, getTas2, getTas3, getTas4, getTas5)


  boxes.map((item, index) => {
    displayBoxes(item, index)
  })

})




function displayBoxes(item, index) {
  for (b = 0; b < item; b++) {
    let box = document.createElement('div')
    box.classList.add('compart')
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        box.classList.add('red')
        break
      case 1:
        box.classList.add('blue')
        break
      case 2:
        box.classList.add('green')
        break
      case 3:
        box.classList.add('yellow')
        break
      case 4:
        box.classList.add('pink')
        break
    }

    box.innerHTML = `<div></div>`
    results.appendChild(box)
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 1050px;
  margin: auto;
}

.formContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.buttonZone {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.formTitle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inputZone {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#resultContainer {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
}

.stack {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.compart {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 3px;
}

.case {
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="formContainer">
    <div class="formTitle">How many boxes ?</div>
    <div class="inputZone">
      <input type="number" class="Qty1">
      <input type="number" class="Qty2">
      <input type="number" class="Qty3">
      <input type="number" class="Qty4">
      <input type="number" class="Qty5">
    </div>
    <div class="buttonZone">
      <button id="qtyButton">Go</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="resultContainer">
    <div class="stack"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get you. You can add HTML dynamically through JS